# GDM3 How to set backing store options with Xorg

Tags: xorg

I want to turn on the X11 backing store for *all* windows.  To do this I need to pass the `-wm` option to `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg`.  However GDM3 has the starting of Xorg wrapped up in all sorts of configuration, but as far as I can tell, it does not expose this option.

Is there some other way to configure GDM3 to give Xorg this option?

The only thing I can find so far, mentioned in is [this documentation](http://www.fifi.org/doc/gdm/html/C/x156.html), is to completely specify the Xorg command line in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

```
[daemon]
    ...
    StandardXServer=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -wm
```

But typically Xorg is started with a lot of other options too, my typical process list gives this:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

However, even with this full option set, GDM3 seems to ignore it.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I have modified `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, to contain:

```
[xdmcp]
ServerArguments=-wm
```

But it does not seem to be honoured by GDM3, as the process list shows this argument is missing from the `Xorg` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-backing-store.conf` with following content:

```
Section "Device"
  Option "BackingStore" "on"
EndSection
```

(from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464945/64590))